# Webview takes long time to load

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am using webview in my application. And i have found that it takes long time to load webpage other than webpage open in mobile browser.

Is there anyways by which I can increase the speed of webview load ???

Comment: Without codes, how can we know the problems?

Comment: i think u dint read my post properly.

Comment: loading speed depends on content & its structure.

Answer (score 1):

Laoding webview in android not only depends on the internet speed , it changes form device to device based on OS version and configuration, 
`loadUrl(url)`  is only method to load data... if inter net speed is less then keep you html file in assets and give that path(url) to load file ...

Answer (score 0):

try loadData method, it might be a bit faster.

```
String sumry;

...//convert your file to a string and store in sumry variable

  webview.loadData(sumry, "text/html", null);
```